# Getting error "fatal: could not open '.git/MERGE_HEAD' " when committing

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-commit, git-pull

getting error trying to do "git commit -m '...' "

```
fatal: could not open '.git/MERGE_HEAD' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I am working on a branch and am trying to pull from master but i need to commit first

Comment: It seems you're in the middle of a merge, what does `git status` say?

Comment: it says the branch that I am currently on and the changes that are to be committed

Answer (score 1):

The MERGE_HEAD file is there for when you are in the middle of merging two branches.  It is likely that your current branch is in a defunct merge state.

If you are using Git > 1.6.1, you can use `git reset --merge` to restore your current branch back to the state it was in before the merge.

Then you can commit and finally merge master:

```sh
git commit -m "Some message"
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout {branch}
git merge master
```

Comment: So for the merge, i get a merge conflict and when i resolve it and do git status, i get "changes to be committed" and "unmerged paths", under unmerged paths, i get "both modified" and file name. As for local changes i dont have any, I am on branch which is basically the old master, and trying to pull the newest master branch

Comment: So why do you say you need to commit first? Is it because git is saying so?

Comment: yes, I am trying to pull, apply my changes then commit and push, when i resolve the merge conflicts and try to commit i get the error message

Comment: i think another question that would help me would be, is there any way I can change the current branch that i am on to force pull the master branch, getting rid of all local changes, making my branch the exact copy of master branch

Comment: Yes, from the root of your project: `git checkout .` then `git merge master`.

Comment: okay now i dont know what happened but trying git pull origin master says "already up to date" even though the remote master branch is different